# What unit is `getFitnessScore()` in the IterativeClosestPoint class from PCL returning?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I use the `pcl::IterativeClosestPoint` method from the Point-Cloud-Library.
As of right now it seems that the documentation of it is offline. 
Here in google [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_cuztbMnheoJ:docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_registration.html%20&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de). And also a [tutorial](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nXx5fnFN6LkJ:pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de).

There is a possibility to call `icp.getFitnessScore()` to get the mean squared distances from the points of the two clouds. I just can't find information on what kind of unit this is indicated. Does anyone knows what the number I get there means? For example output for me was: `0,0003192`. This seems to be low, but I have no clue if it is meters, centimeters, feet, or whatever.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The scale depends on your input data. If it's in meter then the output is in meter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what kind of unit is `icp.getFitnessScore()` used?

Like Joy said in his comment, ***the unit is the same as your input data***.
For example, your input point cloud might comes from a [obj file](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/). And a point will be stored like `v 9.322 -1.0778 0.44997`. The number returned by `icp.getFitnessScore()` will have the same unit as the point's coordinate.

---

> Does anyone knows what the number I get there means?

The number you get represents ***the mean squared distance from each point in source to its closest point in target***.

That is to say, if you assume **every point** in *source* has a corresponding point in *target*, and the correspondence set comes from **closest point data association**, then the number represents the mean squared distance between all correspondences. That can be seen from the source code below.

To make more sense of the function, you might want to filter out correspondences that have a large distance between them. (The two point cloud might only partially overlap.) And the function actually has an optional parameter `max_range` that does this.

---

The method `getFitnessScore()` is defined in `pcl::Registration`, the base class of `pcl::IterativeClosestPoint`. The optional parameter `max_range` is defaulted to be `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, as you can see in the [definition](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/registration/include/pcl/registration/registration.h#L394):

```cpp
/** \brief Obtain the Euclidean fitness score (e.g., sum of squared distances from the source to the target)
  * \param[in] max_range maximum allowable distance between a point and its correspondence in the target 
  * (default: double::max)
  */
inline double 
getFitnessScore (double max_range = std::numeric_limits<double>::max ());
```

---

And the [source code](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/registration/include/pcl/registration/impl/registration.hpp#L119) of this function is:

```cpp
template <typename PointSource, typename PointTarget, typename Scalar> inline double
pcl::Registration<PointSource, PointTarget, Scalar>::getFitnessScore (double max_range)
{

  double fitness_score = 0.0;

  // Transform the input dataset using the final transformation
  PointCloudSource input_transformed;
  transformPointCloud (*input_, input_transformed, final_transformation_);

  std::vector<int> nn_indices (1);
  std::vector<float> nn_dists (1);

  // For each point in the source dataset
  int nr = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input_transformed.points.size (); ++i)
  {
    // Find its nearest neighbor in the target
    tree_->nearestKSearch (input_transformed.points[i], 1, nn_indices, nn_dists);

    // Deal with occlusions (incomplete targets)
    if (nn_dists[0] <= max_range)
    {
      // Add to the fitness score
      fitness_score += nn_dists[0];
      nr++;
    } 
  } 

  if (nr > 0)
    return (fitness_score / nr);
  else
    return (std::numeric_limits<double>::max ());

}
```